# Why can't I do math in a class property declaration?

Tags: php, properties

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php shows the following example which fails for me.

```
class SimpleClass{
   private $var3 = 1+2;
}
```

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting ',' or ';'....`

Any ideas why?

php version 5.4.9

Comment: 5 lines above the example,  on the page you linked: `// invalid property declarations:`

Comment: funny link to the page saying this cant be done

Comment: you have to read the _entire_ example

Comment: ha, facepalm, i read every line in the page EXCEPT that. Must not have noticed the orange comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation never states that it is a valid property declaration.  It specifically states its an *invalid* example.

directly from your link

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
   public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
   public $var3 = 1+2;
   public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
   public $var5 = $myVar;

   // valid property declarations:
   public $var6 = myConstant;
   public $var7 = array(true, false);

   // This is allowed only in PHP 5.3.0 and later.
   public $var8 = <<<'EOD'
hello world
EOD;
}
?>
```

this is just how the language syntax is defined for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a default value for a property should be done inside the constructor. To add default values when declaring the property is just a non-OO thing that rolls in PHP to make live for developers easier, but -- as you can see -- it isn't supported very well yet.

The solution:

```php
class Foo
{
    private $var;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->var = 2 + 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support calculated values, even though both values technically can be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can't in PHP.  You can't have evaluated property assignments aloong with declarations in PHP.  Not sure why it was implemented this way.